# Old questions are still not marked as solved - What should be the action here?

Tags: discussion

While surfing, I came up with following question:

[How to restrict access to custom component views?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5388/how-to-restrict-access-to-custom-component-views/)

Which was asked asked 5 months ago. We've received lot of good answers over this question. But any of these answers are not marked as **"accepted"**.

Is there any provision for moderators (or correct person) to mark relevant answer as **"Accepted"** So that, people will get to know that, "Yeah! this is a correct way out of all."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, moderators cannot accept an answers. This needs to be done by the OP, so the best thing you can do is comment on the question or answer and tag the OP's name to let them know.

Comment: Ok so if in case OP is not responding since long time then,  will there be something that should be done from our side?

Comment: All we can do is comment to ask them to accept an answer. If they fail to do this, then nothing can be done.

Comment: Hopefully this wouldn't matter because the best answer would have the most upvotes :)

Comment: @moomoochoo - True, however I believe accepted answers contributes to "answered questions" which you can see in [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla) :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I was wondering about the same. There are many questions with good answers that solve/answer the question that have not been marked as "SOLVED" (accepted).

As a step we can take, is to upvote those answers that provide a good solution, although an accepted answer always help better.

I agree that we shall comment on these questions, asking the OP to accept the answer that helped him solve or come closer to the solution.

#### Update:

I just found this [Marking Questions as Answered](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/marking-questions-as-answered?rq=1), which is suggesting against asking the OP to accept an answer.